# c compiler has a function stuck in its namespace (maybe?). mac

Tags: c, macos

A week ago I made a function called getline in a code that didn't work. Since then, whenever I name a function getline and try to compile it, it doesn't work. If I change the name of the function to something else, it works again. I have restarted my computer (though it really shouldn't require that). How can I get this namespace back?

example error message:

```
Numens-MBP:c examples mycotic$ cc testing.c
testing.c:9:5: error: conflicting types for 'getline'
int getline(void);
    ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:448:9: note: previous declaration is here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict __linep, size_t * __restrict __lineca...
        ^
testing.c:13:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'
      [-Wimplicit-int]
main()
^
testing.c:20:24: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 0
        while ((len = getline()) > 0)
                      ~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:448:1: note: 'getline' declared here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict __linep, size_t * __restrict __lineca...
^
testing.c:36:5: error: conflicting types for 'getline'
int getline(void)
    ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:448:9: note: previous declaration is here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict __linep, size_t * __restrict __lineca...
        ^
1 warning and 3 errors generated.
```

Comment: Are you sure that using "getline" as a function name worked before? What else did happen between "it worked" and "does not work anymore"? Switch of platform? Switch of compiler? Change anything about headers (location, naming)?

Comment: In your previous use of your `getline` function, where you on a Windows (or other non-POSIX) system? Or were you programming C++?

Answer (score 2):

[`getline()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) is a standard C library function. Your function is conflicting with the definition in the standard library.

Pick another name for your function. This one is taken.

Comment: Not really, it's standard on [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) platforms. It's not a standard C function.

Answer (score 1):

The [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) function is a part of POSIX 2008; it was not a part of POSIX 2001 or POSIX 1997.  On a Mac, even when you specify `-std=c11`, the POSIX definitions are enabled by default.

You can work around it by specifying a POSIX version that did not support `getline()`.  Consider this code — but ignore the fact that this '`getline()`' outputs a line:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int getline(int);

int getline(int num)
{
    printf("%s: %d\n", __func__, num);
    return num + 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("RV = %d\n", getline(i));
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with GCC 7.1.0, or with either the `gcc` or `clang` from XCode 8.3.2, generates all sorts of problems because of the conflicting type of `getline()` from POSIX and `getline()` as defined in this code unless you add arguments to prevent the problem.  The source was in file `gl23.c`.

```
$ /usr/bin/clang -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
>                -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition gl23.c -o gl23 
gl23.c:3:12: error: conflicting types for 'getline'
extern int getline(int);
           ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:448:9: note: previous declaration is here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict __linep, size_t * __restrict __linecapp, FILE * __restrict __stream) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTIN...
        ^
gl23.c:5:5: error: conflicting types for 'getline'
int getline(int num)
    ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:448:9: note: previous declaration is here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict __linep, size_t * __restrict __linecapp, FILE * __restrict __stream) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTIN...
        ^
gl23.c:14:38: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 1
        printf("RV = %d\n", getline(i));
                            ~~~~~~~  ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:448:1: note: 'getline' declared here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict __linep, size_t * __restrict __linecapp, FILE * __restrict __stream) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTIN...
^
3 errors generated.
$
```

However, if you specify conformance with the old versions of POSIX by adding `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L` or `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199506L`, then it compiles cleanly, and runs properly, producing:

```
getline: 0
RV = 1
getline: 1
RV = 2
getline: 2
RV = 3
getline: 3
RV = 4
getline: 4
RV = 5
```

Be aware that this is only a band-aid solution and it has ramifications — all the other nice new features of POSIX 2008 are no longer accessible.

The only long-term solution is to accept that `getline()` is now a part of the 'standard' C namespace — the standard is POSIX, of course, not ISO/IEC 9899:2011 — and rename the function.  (Yes, it's a nuisance, and K&R 2nd Edition illustrates three versions of `getline()` that are no longer OK because of this.  I had to rename my library function because of this.  And the name was not in the reserved namespaces in prior versions of POSIX; there was no way to guess that it would be necessary.)